# Is it possible to see information such as horsepower and torque of cars in GRID 2?

Tags: grid-2

Is there some way to get this information about the cars (like real horsepower, torque, tire size etc.) in GRID 2?
The only thing I have seen is a graphic bar but nothing in absolute numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not - the only vehicle statistics shown by the game are the overview statistics you've already mentioned, which are shown when selecting a car;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can, but only by using a mod program to inspect the files on PC.

You'll have to grab the CTF Editor from [here](http://www.petartasev.com/modding/ego-engine/).

After downloading it follow the instructions in the readme to extract, and run it.

In the editor, switch to the Other tab, and use File -> Open to browse for ctf files located in the grid 2/cars/models/xxx (ex: for mustang mach 1 xxx = mac) folder of your Grid 2 installation directory.

Once the file is open you can scroll to power, for example, and right click the value to see the power curve values. I believe the values are in SI units. (rad/s, Watts)